# User input to update macro

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I want to create a macro that will access a site and copy a table.
The catch is, I want the user to be able to chose which one via prompt window.

The pull info code goes:

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/aaaaa/bbbb/user_list.php? 
month=202001&user_id=999&group_id=1""))
```

which works fine.

The part I want the user to update is the month part.

```
Dim Response As String
Response = InputBox("input date*YYYYMM*")
```

And tried to add Response after month=

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/aaaaa/bbbb/user.php? 
month=""Response""&user_id=999&group_id=1""))
```

> Run-time error'6':Overflow

I understand that the macro doesn't understand my request, but hoped someone will be able to tell me what am I missing.

Comment: Please edit your tags and include which program you are using eg Excel, MS-Word, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should look like this:

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/aaaaa/bbbb/user.php?month=" & Response & "&user_id=999&group_id=1"))
```

You need to concatenate strings with the `&` sign.

```
FullString = "string a" & "string b" & variable1
```

Comment: I have tried to add the & string & between like you advised. However, i receive
    Run-time error "1004"
    Application-defined or object-defined error.

    
This is the edited line:

Source = 
    Web.Page(Web.Contents(""http://192.168.2.20/what_tools/total/user_list.php? 
    month="" & Respons & ""&user_id=118&group_id=1""))

Comment: Ok found the error.
the brackets where wrong...How  (""192.168.2.20/what_tools/total/user_list.php? month=" & Respons & "&user_id=118&group_id=1""))
2 brackets at the start and finish, and one in the middle(start finish).
Thx!